# elasticsearch aggs and query size

Tags: elasticsearch

i use elasticsearch but i have a little problem with the aggs because i set a size for my query like

```
$params ['body'] ['size'] = 1;
```

and i use aggs like

```
$params ['body'] ['aggs'] ['grouped_by_name'] = array (
            "terms" => array (
                    "field" => "title",
                    "size" => 0 
            ) 
    );
```

but in my doc_count i receive more than 1 why ?

What can i do to only receive the aggs i needed

Comment: What aggs do you need? Your query does not have any filter to reduce the number of documents on which aggs will be computed. You simply set the number of hits to return to 1. It will match all documents given that there are no filters. As a result, the aggs will be computed over all documents and hence you may get `doc_count` whose value is greater than 1.

Comment: the query as a lot of filter the problem is a have some document with the same title so i would like to have a doc_count which count only one document for my query

Answer (score 0):

```
$params ['body'] ['size'] = 1;  <------ this is how much hits you want, 0 mean 0

$params ['body'] ['aggs'] ['grouped_by_name'] = array (
        "terms" => array (
                "field" => "title",
                "size" => 1 <-------------- this size is how much of this aggs you want, 0 mean infinity 
        ) 
);
```

Comment: Thanks but that does not work, when i do that my query return only the first term of my fields : example i use a field who contains an array of term if i do that only the first term will appear

Comment: yes it is normal that it return only the first because it limit the agg to 1 result, not the aggs of the field of one document. 
please update your question with the some of the data you have and what you want . maybe you need to filter the data on the document you want, and make aggs on it/them